# Windows Form + Excel Worksheet

Tags: c#, windows, forms, excel, vba

I've built a windows application that retrieves information from an Excel Worksheet.  I've tested and had it working on a computer with Microsoft Office Package installed.

I have a little problem now, I will be deploying this program to multiple workstations but they have OpenOffice installed.  My issue is, do these workstations need have Microsoft Office installed or would it work regardless?

Thank you all.

Comment: `OpenOffice` and `MS Office` are two different programs. They are not directly compatible (with VBA) at least.

Comment: I am not sure what your application does, but there is always the option of working with .CSV files if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referencing the MS Office object library, then they need to have it installed.

Edit: You can probably install Open Office on your machine, write a similar call for that object library, and have it choose based on the installed program(s).